# Minimum length of confidence interval for $\theta$ when $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim\operatorname{Beta}( \theta,1)$

Tags: probability, statistics, numerical-optimization, confidence-interval

I am asked to find the minimum length confidence interval for a Beta distribution with parameters $a=\theta$ and $b=1$ and probability $1-\alpha$.

I have found that $-2\theta \sum_i \log(X_i)$ has distribution $\chi^2_{2n}$ and is therefore a pivotal quantity. However, I don't know how to find the minimum length confidence interval: I know I have to find two points $a, b$ such that $F(b) - F(a) = 1-\alpha$ and $f(b) = f(a)$ but I don't know how to tackle the problem numerically. Am I right on my approach until now? How should I approach the problem of solving for $b$ and $a$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your approach looks fine upto this.

Comment: @StubbornAtom All right, thank you. Do you have any hint about how can I find the minimum length confidence internval?

Comment: Please avoid [cross-posting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/465608/119261) at the same time; choose where you want to ask.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I will delete the other one as soon one of them gets an answer. I didn’t know cross-posting was discouraged.